# Trying to stream virtualy created camera video0 device to make rtsp stream for VLC using gstreamer in 24bit RGB format

Tags: c++, video-streaming, gstreamer, v4l2, v4l2loopback

I have created Video0 device using V4l2loopback and used the following sample Git code [V4l2Loopback_cpp](https://github.com/eruffaldi/v4l2loopback_cpp) as a application to stream jpg images from a folder sequential by altering some conditions in the code.But the code read images as 24Bit RGB image and send it Video0 device which is fine ,because the image run like a proper video on VLC video device capture. As i mentioned earlier thet if i checked the VLC properties of the video its Shows the following content [image]

i need this video0 device to stream rtsp h264 video in vlc using the gstreamer lib .
i have used the following command to check in commandline for testing but its show some internal process error

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,width=590,height=332,framerate=30/1 ! x264enc ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96
```

i dont know whats the problem here .is it 24bit jpeg format or the gstreamer command i use. I need a proper gstreamer command line to process the video0 devide to stream h264 rtsp video any help is appreciated  thank u.

image Format - jpg (sequence image passed)
Video0 recives - 24-bit RGB image
output need - h264 rtsp stream from video0

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is a solution, but the following may help:

1. You may try adjusting resolution according to what V4L reports (width=584) :

```
v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=584,height=332,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96
```

2. Note that this error may happen on v4l2loopback receiver side while it may be a sender error. If you're feeding v4l2loopback with a gstreamer pipeline to v4l2sink, you would try adding identity such as:

```
... ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=584,height=332,framerate=30/1 ! identity drop-allocation=1 ! v4l2sink
```

Comment: i have tried this as command in gst_launch-1.0 "v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! video/x-raw,format=RGB,width=584,height=332,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc insert-vui=1 ! h264parse ! rtph264pay name=pay0 pt=96 "
but i dont know which port its sending the packet ,can u help with that and will it be a TCP packet or UDP i have tried adding 

And when i try to run in testlaunch.c by gstream examples i get the following error 


(Gstremer_img2vid2:882329): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 05:37:12.550: gst_bin_get_by_name: assertion 'GST_IS_BIN (bin)' failed

Comment: These pipelines are not complete, note these have no sink. These are expected to be provided as H264 source to RSTP server example such as test-launch. Test-launch will manage the connection, ports and protocols, and add what it needs to your source sub-pipeline. Be sure to use test-launch example sources from the same gstreamer version you are running.